# How to stop a program from closing when a file doesn't exist/cannot run

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm trying to create a MP3 player in Python and I let the user run MP3s by inputting the name of the file. The only problem is, if the user inputs an incorrect name or a name that doesn't exist... the script closes. I was wondering if there would be a way to say:

if filedoesnotexist:

skip this line of code

Here's the actual code I'm using in the script:

```
class player():
    def player_name():
        Minput= input("Insert name of mp3: ")
        os.startfile("MP3_folder\\" +Minput + ".mp3")
        input("Input a key to end playback: ")
        os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM wmplayer.exe")
```

Comment: Why can't you use a [`try`/`except`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions) block?

Comment: I'm a Python newbie. I'll take a look at what you linked and see if I can figure this out.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html, scroll down to 8.3 for the try-except

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to simply "skip this line of code" if a user enters an incorrect file name, you could use a `try`/`except` block, like so:

```
class player():
    def player_name():
        Minput= input("Insert name of mp3: ")
        try:
            os.startfile("MP3_folder\\" +Minput + ".mp3")
        except OSError:
            pass
        input("Input a key to end playback: ")
        os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM wmplayer.exe")
```

If you wanted it to return back to the beginning of the loop when/if an incorrect value is entered, you could try and use a `While True` loop; something like is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828771/how-to-go-back-to-first-if-statement-if-no-choices-are-valid).